# A problem with System.DllNotFoundException in the dll file created by including ippiFFTGetSize_C_32fc ().(intel IPP)

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, intel-ipp

I created a `dll` created using the `IPP function ippiFFTGetSize_C_32fc ()`.
Referencing this dll file from wpf project (c #) results in `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'TEST.dll'` error.

```
int HioTest(Ipp32fc* csSrcImg, Ipp32fc* csDstImg)
{

    // FFT Init
    IppiFFTSpec_C_32fc  *pSpec = NULL;                              /* Pointer to FFT spec structure */
    Ipp8u               *pMemInit = NULL, *pBuffer = NULL;          /* Pointer to the work buffers */
    int                 sizeSpec = 0, sizeInit = 0, sizeBuf = 0;    /* Size of FFT spec structure, init and work buffers */
    int               order = 9;

    ippiFFTGetSize_C_32fc(order, order, IPP_FFT_DIV_INV_BY_N, ippAlgHintAccurate, &sizeSpec, &sizeInit, &sizeBuf);

    return 5;
}
```

I created a `TEST.dll` (C language) using IPP for External library. I want to refer to `TEST.dll` in my wpf project and use it.

The tool used is "visual studio 2017" and the IPP version uses the latest version of `compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144`.

See the IPP documentation. The settings of the dll project,

- Debug / x64
- Add `ippsmt.lib, ippcoremt.lib` for `Additional Dependencies`.
- Automatic "single-threaded DLL" setting.
- `export .def` created.
- Add `ippInit ()` to dllmain.cpp
- Referencing from C # . /clr setting

C # project

- Debug / x64
- unlock the loader
- Increase the reserve stack size

I set it up like this.

`Other ippMalloc (), ippsAdddC_32f_I ()`

The `dll` file I created using the above worked properly in my wpf project. However, TEST.dll containing `ippiFFTGetSize_C_32fc ()` will result in an error `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'TEST.dll'`.
I want to know the cause or solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, once try cleaning and the rebuilding it.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
But I tried, the problem is not solved.

Comment: Try placing TEST.dll  file into the same folder in which executable file is present.

Comment: Sadly, the dll file is already put together with the executable file. It is referenced as another dll file (which I created and worked normally). Strangely, the function in question has a "not found dll" error.